# exporting gre modules function

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am writing a Netfilter hook func which hooks at `INET_PRE_ROUTING`. Inside this hook function I want to access `ipgre_tunnel_locate()`defined in `ip_gre.c` as static. On viewing `/proc/kallsyms` the `ipgre_tunnel_locate()` is listed as follows:

```
ffffffffa03acb30 t ipgre_tunnel_locate  [ip_gre]
```

The second column in the above implies that the function is local and unexported. Can I export this function using `EXPORT_SYMBOL(ipgre_tunnel_locate)` in `ip_gre.c so` that I can use it in my NetFilter prerouting hook function??? `

Is there any strong reason why the function is not exported in kernel by default ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the function, but your module will be able to run with your patched kernel only.

I think, the reason it is not exported is simple: this is not a part of external interface. For example, since `3.10` version of kernel, there is no `ipgre_tunnel_locate()`.

I should say again that exporting symbols just because you need them is not a reliable technique.